# Почему не получается осуществить переход на другое активити из синглтона android?

Tags: android, android-intent, context, singleton

У меня есть синглтон, в котором находится функция которая отвечает за логаут из приложения. При логауте я хочу "забывать" два моих токена и ставить идентификатор посещения на "false" и переходить интентом на стартовый экран приложения. В итоге все забывается, идентификатор вроде как меняется, а перехода нету. Либо он есть но тогда идентификатор не ставится на "false". Вот функция:

```
public void logOut() {
        SharedPreferences sp1 = context.getSharedPreferences("access_token",0);
        sp1.edit().remove("access_token").apply();

        SharedPreferences sp2 = context.getSharedPreferences("refresh_token",0);
        sp2.edit().remove("refresh_token").apply();

        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("hasVisited",0);
        sp.edit().putBoolean("hasVisited", false).apply();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

как я понял что токены стираются? Все просто - у меня не идет запрос, тело токена пустое и запрос не проходит. Но почему-то идентификатор посещения приложения не сбрасывается, либо переход неверно сделан. Сама переменная `context` равна такому:

```
MySingleton.getInstance().setContext(getApplicationContext());
```

то есть вроде как значение этой переменной правильное потому-что запись и стирание в настройки идет нормально. Но что-то идет не так как нужно и я не могу понять что именно. Надеюсь на дельные советы и помощь.

### UPDATE

так как у меня в разных местах моего приложения может понадобится обновление токена, то я в функции обновления токена закинул идентификатор места с которого пришел запрос на обновление токена и дальше я открываю ту активити с которой пришел запрос или функцию в том классе. Вот как у меня теперь выглядит кусок кода там где в функции для обновления токенов осуществляется переход на активити:

```
switch (id) {
case 1:
getPersonalData();
break;
case 2:
Log.w("MY_TAG", "Message_center");
Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MessageCenter.class);
intent.putExtra("id", type);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
context.startActivity(intent);
break;
case 3:
Log.w("MY_TAG", "Message_show");
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MessageShow.class);
intent1.putExtra("message_id",message_id);
intent1.putExtra("type",type);
intent1.putExtra("sender",sender_from_message);
intent1.putExtra("token",acc_token);
intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
context.startActivity(intent1);
break;
}
```

а вот обновленная функция логаута:

```
public void logOut() {
        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0);
        sp.edit().remove("access_token").apply();
        sp.edit().remove("refresh_token").apply();
        sp.edit().putBoolean("hasVisited", false).apply();

        Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

вроде все одинаково, но логаут не работает, и я не могу понять почему.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, не помогло, активити просто перезагрузилась походу и все

Comment: Зачем столько экземпляров SharedPreferences?! Ты под каждое значение отдельное хранилище получаешь.

Comment: я еще плохо умею работать с этой стороной приложения)) нужно будет походу подправить немного)

Comment: Так и ясно что у вас не работает. Активист раньше не запускалось? Или проблема вообще не в запуске активити?

Comment: проблема в том что я не могу осуществить переход на другое активити с использованием стандартного интента

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, да, судя по всему стандартным интентом это нельзя сделать если вы используете контекст приложения, а не активити. Флаг из первого коммента решает эту проблему. Но вы говорите что не решает. Постарайтесь переформулировать вопрос. Наверное у вас с префами проблема? Или просто не нравится то, что активити пересоздаётся?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, нет с префами у меня было все хорошо, а после 3 коммента вообще стало все прекрасно. Я наверное переформулирую вопрос, с учетом новых данных :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка лежала на поверхности, так получилось что я создал кучу хранилищ для разных переменных в памяти устройства, и при попытке логаута я обращался не к тому хранилищу и пытался изменить переменную "has_visited". Теперь у меня все переменные в одном хранилище и это решило мою проблему.